# How to get profile Id of user's friends using Graph API

Tags: android, mysql, facebook, facebook-graph-api, timeline

We want only the Public Profile ID of user's friends. User in our case is the end user who signs up our Android App and we store their access token every time they log in. We current have user's public profile ID and his user access token.

We are creating a timeline for our application and thus we would require public profile id of all user's friends and insert into our MySQL DB so as to keep track of the social circle.

Any other solution to implement timeline is acceptable.

**Note:** As pointed out in answer, facebook is no longer allowing developers to access user's friends' data.

Comment: This question was already answered and closed, yet downvotes? Can anyone explain the reason behind downvotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since v2.0 of the Graph API, it is not possible to get access to all friends anymore. You can only get friends who authorized your App too with `/me/friends`. More information: [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)

Comment: Thanks so much. You guided us in right direction. :)